# Did the default font of question titles change recently?

Tags: support, design

I may be wrong but I think the font face of Super User question titles has changed or become **bold** recently. Am I right or is Firefox playing games on me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fonts used for the headers [*have* changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112172/question-title-font-has-changed).

The font selection for headers is now:

```
'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

It apparently used to be:

```
Trebuchet MS, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel better now knowing my eyes didn't deceive me. :)